# Stored procedure not inserting data into table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to implement a stored procedure like this where it's going to compare `UserID` from another table. If that user id already exists in `dbo.user` info table, it will insert data into `[dbo].[BulkUploadTagDetail]` table.

Every time I execute this stored procedure running into an issue that the data doesn't get inserted into my database table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertBulkUploadTagDetail]
    (@BulkTagID INT,
     @PortalUserID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
     @EmailAddress VARCHAR(256),
     @BulkUploadFileName VARCHAR(256),
     @CreatedOn DATETIME2(7),
     @IsCompleted BIT = 0)
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    IF EXISTS (SELECT UserID
               FROM dbo.UserInfo
               WHERE UserID = @PortalUserID)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [unp]
        SET [unp].[BulkTagID] = @BulkTagID,
            [unp].[UserID] = @PortalUserID,
            [unp].[EmailAddress] = @EmailAddress,
            [unp].[BulkUploadFileName] = @BulkUploadFileName,
            [unp].[CreatedOn] = GETUTCDATE(),
            [unp].[IsCompleted] = @IsCompleted
        FROM 
            [dbo].[InsertBulkUploadTagDetail] unp
        INNER JOIN
            [dbo].[UserInfo] uinfo ON [unp].[UserID] = [uinfo].[UserID]
        WHERE
            [unp].[UserID] = @PortalUserID
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[BulkUploadTagDetail] 
                    ([BulkTagID], [PortalUserID], [EmailAddress],
                     [BulkUploadFileName], [CreatedOn], [IsCompleted])
        VALUES (@BulkTagID, @PortalUserID, @EmailAddress,
                @BulkUploadFileName, @CreatedOn, @IsCompleted)
    END
END
```

Comment: Your use of *exists* here is [completely unecessary](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern)

Comment: Have you tested both queries outside the SP?

Comment: Nobody here can guess your business rules, however... the exists check is on `dbo.UserInfo` but the update and insert are on different tables. If you're trying to update existing data in `dbo.InsertBulkUploadTagDetail` should the exists check be on that instead?

Comment: Sounds like the `EXISTS` check should itself have a join. But as mentioned you don't need an `EXISTS` anyway, just use a `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0` check